# Assembling Thumb on Rasparian

Tags: arm, assembly

Has anyone been successful in assembling, compiling and running thumb or thumb-2 on Rasparian. Here is an example of my assembly code:

```
.text
.global main
.code 16
main:
      MOV r3,#1
finish:
      bx lr
```

I have been attempting to use gas for assembly and gcc to compile:

```
as -o multiply.o multiply.s
gcc -mthumb -o multiply multiply.o
```

Both run without a complaint but when I attempt to run the code in GDB I get a SIGILL:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8392
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/Dev/assembly_files/multiply 

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00008390 in main ()
```

So, I'm uncertain if its something I am doing wrong or if I need to change my toolchain or other? I appreciate any advice. Also know that normal 32-bit ARM assembles, compiles and runs like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

your program cannot just end, it's supposed to make a system call, that returns the control to the operating system. also, this is totally off topic here.

Comment: I'm uncertain how this is off-topic? I am using a raspberry-pi and I'm fairly certain writing code on it requires some specific libraries of code which other raspberry pi developers would be aware of. My code did have a mistake which I have resolved but the question still remains. Should I be capable of assembling thumb on raspberry pi using a linux based distro?

Comment: Why would it be offtopic?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen basic programming questions, like falling off the end of assembly program without calling the system about program exit, have nothing to do with Raspberry Pi, IMNSHO.

Comment: Raspberry Pi assembly programming?  Well, as good a forum as any if it as a starter question and it can inspire others.  Anyway, if you consider a question off-topic, flag it as so, so it can be migrated. Note that e.g. SO puts higher standards regarding question effort than might be possible for a hobbyist learning to program.